# How to stop character encoding in thymeleaf from changing url get parameter '?' character to changing to %3F

Tags: thymeleaf

code is like:-

```
<a th:href="@{{path}(path=${templatebitcointalkforumlink})}"
```

and from properties file:-

```
eg:- template variable=https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4456828
```

Note:- i don't own this post/topic it's just example

now it changes to:-

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php**%3F**topic=4456827

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `@{...}` if you don't want to take advantage auto encoded parameters, url replacement params, etc..  Instead, just use a regular variable.

```
<a th:href="${templatebitcointalkforumlink}">...</a>
```